# Spark Scala program to store data in HBase

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, hadoop2

I am trying to store a dataset in HBase using a scala program in Eclipse but getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /user/hduser/hbase-staging (exists=false, cwd=file:/home/hduser/workspace/Project)
```

I have also given all the necessary permission to hdfs directory:

```
drwxrwxrwx   - hduser supergroup          0 2017-02-17 13:57 /user/hduser/hbase-staging
```

and as well as to my working directory `/home/hduser/workspace/Project`

```
drwxrwxrwx  6 hduser hduser 4096 Feb 17 14:08 Project
```

But the error is still persisting.

Comment: `exists=false` would say that directory does not actually exist on HDFS... Show the commands you used to create them yourself

Comment: I checked it. Directory is already there. 
hduser@master:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2017-02-14 21:29 /user/hduser/.sparkStaging
drwxrwxrwx   - hduser supergroup          0 2017-02-17 13:57 /user/hduser/hbase-staging

Comment: Does `spark-env.sh` point to the `hdfs://` file URI, or the `file://` URI configuration file from your `core-site.xml`?

Comment: I again deleted it and created it using the following command: hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hduser/hbase-staging

Comment: My spark-env.sh contains the following:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala/scala-2.11.8
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=10.0.0.1
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3

Comment: Could you please let me know how can I point hdfs:// in spark-env.sh.

Comment: Your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` should contain some XML files such as core-site.xml. Look in there and/or go back over how to setup hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode

Comment: core-site.xml contains:
<configuration>
 <property>        
  <name>fs.default.name</name>         
  <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>         
  <description>NameNode URI</description>     
 </property>
 <property> 
        <name>dfs.permissions</name> 
        <value>false</value> 
    </property>
</configuration>

Comment: Okay, so `hdfs://master:9000/` seems to be okay, but I would use the full domain name there... Maybe it's trying to create the folder on your local filesystem

Comment: I am running program in eclipse. Is there anything else I can do in my code to avoid this problem.

Comment: Eclipse shouldn't matter, but you can create a Jar file and spark-submit that on the cluster itself

Comment: Jar was working but I want to do it from IDE. Any suggestion please.

Comment: If the jar worked, then there's something wrong with your classpath, and I unfortunately don't know what what that could be

Comment: Thanks for your reply.